# Dcotrine QueryBuilder with manyToMany relationship

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, query-builder

In this project I want to create a chat with Mercure protocol and Symfony, So I created two entities: Conversation which can have many users and User entity which can have also many conversations, my problem is I don't know how to **find a conversation by his users**, and **find all converation by a user**.

---

```php
#../Entity/Conversation.php
class Conversation
{
  // ....

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="conversations")
   */
  private $users;
}
```

---

```php
#../Entity/User.php
class User
{
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Conversation::class, mappedBy="users")
   */
  private $conversations;
  // ...
}
```

---

```php
# Repository/ConversationRepository.php
/**
* @param User[] $users 
*/
public function findOneConversationByUsers(array $users): ?Conversation
{
  // Every convesation is defined by his users
  // The main goal is to find a conversation by his users
  $qb =  $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
  // ...
}

/**
* @return Conversation[]
*/
public function findConversationsByUser(User $user): array
{
  // Each user can have many conversations
  // Each conversation can have many users
  // The main goal is to find all convs by the current user.
  qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
  // $qb-> ...
}
```

### Can you please tell me I can complete the two methods?